# Populate from combobox getting data from sql to pass to textbox on windows from

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datagridview, combobox

Gd Morning Sir/Madam,

I have a windows form which will connect to SQL server via ODBC connection retrieve the information to the combobox and then it will transfer the text to textbox based on combobox selection. Please take a look at the layout of my Form. How will I wrtie the code on C# to do that? Thanks, I just need a short simple code because I am quite new to C#.

Comment: Is it a homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: do you use Google and know how to use it?

Comment: Your form just appears to have a bunch of text in it asking for some code. I don't think it will compile.

Comment: I cant show my form because not allow to. beside the reputation allow me to post images if I have 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. But I am kind of curious with some implementation on windows form for disabling button when running through business implementation logic, is that proper?